# How to add placeholder in Ag Grid when no rows is returned?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I tried using overlayNoRowsTemplate and noRowsOverlayComponent but it only shows these custom values before loading, but once loading is complete and no rows are present then it shows blank.

Answer (score 1):

Once you get response from server and if that's empty, call `gridApi.showNoRowsOverlay()`.

Answer (score 0):

well it should work by default. here is an [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/8ouMSnywsQaCmbDt) where i am getting `noRowsOverlay` even if data returned is null/undefined or just empty array [].

ref: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-overlays/

If this doesnt help care to update the fiddle to reproduce the your issue?